# Jordan form and canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let
$$
 A = \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 4 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
I have to find a Jordan form of a matrix and canonical basis, can someone help me with canonical basis (what is this and how can Ifind it). I have already found Jordan form of a matrix.
Thanks in advance
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
First of all, I found characteristic polynomial $(2 - \lambda)^3(4-\lambda)^2)$. It implies that the algebraic multiplicity of $2$ is $3$ and the algebraic multiplicity of $4$ is $2$  Then I have found $\dim\operatorname{Ker}(A-2I)$, that equals $1$ and $\dim\operatorname{Ker}(A-4I)=1$. That means that I have only $2$ Jordan boxes and I put $1$ above the main diagonal

Comment: How did you find the Jordan form?

Comment: first of all , i found characteristic polynomial ((2 - lambda )^3 - (4 - lambda)^2) . It implies that algebraic multiplicity of lambda1(2) = 3 and lambda2(4) = 2. Then I have found dim of Kernel((A-2I)) , that equals 1 and  dim of Kernel((A-4I)) , that equals 1. That means that I have only 2 Jordan boxes and I put 1 above the main diagonal.

Comment: @Puslan Please add this comment to the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be the linear transformation defined by the matrix $J$.
We start to examine the bottom right block. The canonical basis $\mathcal B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_5\}$ must satisfy $f(v_4)=4v_4$ and $f(v_5)=v_4+4v_5$, i.e. $g(v_4)=0$ and $g(v_5)=v_4$, where $g:=f-4I$. So $v_5\in\ker g^2\setminus\ker g$, $v_4=g(v_5)\neq 0$ and $v_4\in\ker g$.
With some calculations it's easy to see that $\ker g^2=\mathcal L\{\left(1,2,0,0,0\right),\left(-1,0,2,4,0\right)\}$. We can choose $v_5=(-1,0,2,4,0)$ and $v_4=g(v_5)=(6,12,0,0,0)$.

Now, we have to determine $v_1,v_2,v_3$. If $h:=f-2I$, the first three vectors of the base must satisfy: $h(v_1)=0$, $h(v_2)=v_1$ and $h(v_3)=v_2$. Proceeding as before:
$\ker h^3=\mathcal L\{(1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,5,0,2,-4)\}$
$\ker h^2=\mathcal L\{(1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0)\}$
$\ker h=\mathcal L\{(1,0,0,0,0)\}$
Let's choose $v_3=(0,5,0,2,-4)$, $v_2=h(v_3)=(5,0,-6,0,0)$ and $v_1=h(v_2)=(-12,0,0,0,0)$.

You can directly verify that the matrix $$P=\begin{bmatrix}
-12 & 5 & 0 & 6 & -1\\ 
0 & 0 & 5 & 12 & 0\\ 
0 & -6 & 0 & 0 & 2\\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 4\\ 
0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$ satisfies the relation $$J=P^{-1}AP$$

Comment: Thank you a lot

Comment: @Puslan You're welcome! If you found this answer helpful you can upvote my answer and mark this thread as solved. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry , I can not upvote your answer , but I accepted your answer

Comment: How did you found v4 , v2 ,v1

Comment: $v_4$ is the image of $v_5$ through $g$, which is represented by the matrix $A-4I$. So; $$v_4=(A-4I)v_5=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\ 
0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 2\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
2\\ 
4\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
6\\ 
12\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$$ The same happens for $v_2$ and $v_1$ (this time considering the matrix $A-2I$).

Comment: Now I  get it , thank tou